# Automatically use getters and setters with PHP's __get and __set methods?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a base class that all of my classes extend from that allows for property access through simple `$obj->property` syntax, but if `get_property()` or `set_property($value)` is defined, then any attempt to get or set that property is routed through those getters and setters.

The tricky part, though, is that I would like updates to object properties to be reflected in an array (which is a property of the object, call it `$changed_array`) which can output an array of the properties that were changed, for some purpose, say, insertion into a db update call.

The problem lies in this sample:

```
class Sample {
     private $changed_array;

     public __get($var_ame){
         if(method_exists($this, $method = 'get_' . $var_name)){
             return $this->$method();
         } else {
             return $this->$var_name;
         }
     }

     public __set($var_name, $value){
         if(method_exists($this, $method = 'set_' . $var_name))}
             return $this->$method($value);
         } else {
             // pseudo code
             if($this->$var_name isset and isn't $value) { // add to $changed_array }
             return $this->$var_name = $value;
         }
     }
}
```

Which works great, until there is a setter method defined like so:

```
public set_var_name($value){
    // pretend we're mapping a db column to another name
    $this->other_var_name = $value;
}
```

With this, the setter is called, but property it is setting is accessible, so the new value doesn't use the `__set` or `__get` function, and the changed array isn't updated with other_var_name as a changed property.

Is there some kind of hack, other that using something like `$this->set('variable', 'value')` to achieve the result? I would just write getter's and setters, but they vary based on the db schema, and it would be lovely if there was an elegantly simple solution.

Comment: If you want to route everything through your magic methods, why define a public setter?

Comment: For something like remapping a property. If, for instance, the property `token` becomes `private_key`, you can just have `get_private_key()` and `set_private_key($value)` functions map to `$this->token` until the db can be migrated.

Comment: @zerocrates Setter would take variable contents processing like if you have floating point value and in the internal representation you want it to be formatted with exactly 4 digits after floating point.

Comment: I understand why you might want setters, but if the point is to run everything through `__set()` so that it can populate a log of changes, then why not make the setter *private* and force consumers to use `$obj->private_key = 'foo'`, since you already have a `__set()` that will call `set_private_key` in that case?

Comment: using $this->__set(name, value) on each setter seems like the simplest way to do it. It will also allow daisy-chaining of mappings, if they exist.

Comment: @jcinacio which is true, I just wished there was a cleaner way to do it. Planning for the future, I'm not sure if setters will be an oddity, or the norm, so having to return `__set` for each defined setter seems doable, but not ideal.

Comment: @zerocrates even if the setter is private, the object it is setting is within its class scope, so the `__set` function isn't called.

Comment: This is getting extensive for the comments, but my point is, why worry? The code calling `$obj->private_key = 'foo'` is outside the class, so `__set()` does get called and can record a change to `private_key`.  The setter function will actually set the `$token` property, which won't hit `__set()` and won't get recorded, but you've already recorded the change as a change to `private_key`. Of course, this only holds if the setter is private and you're not worried about recording changes truly originating from within the class.

Comment: @zeocrates, you are correct, but I need it to record a change for `token`, which is the variable that `private_key` is getting mapped to.

Comment: Try `parent::$other_var_name = $value;` maybe?

Comment: @petah, `parent::$other_var` may work, but by the same token we could also call `__set` explicitly. I was hoping that there was some obscure php 6+ (sarcasm) call that allowed this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$objects = array("model", "make", "version");
          foreach ($objects as $object) {
              $getter = "get".ucfirst($object);
              if (is_object($iProduct->$getter())) {
                  echo "getvalue"+$iProduct->$getter()
          }
```